# Trying to access a locally-hosted ASP.net service from the Android emulator - not exposed on 127.0.0.1?

Tags: android, asp.net, visual-studio, rest, iis

I'm running an ASP.net service running through Visual Studio.  It's accessible via browser at (example API call) `http://localhost:9000/api/Maps/1`.  When I visit `http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/Maps/1` via browser, I get a 400 error (Bad Request - Invalid Hostname).

The Android emulator can successfully make calls to external sites (e.g. `http://httpbin.org/ip`).  When I direct the app to pull JSON from `http://10.0.2.2:9000/api/Maps/1` (10.0.2.2 being what the web tells me directs the emulator to the host computer's localhost, the result is the HTML for (what I assume is) the same 400 error from 127.0.0.1 above.

It seems when I run the web service from Visual Studio (2013, if that makes a difference), it's exposed properly on localhost, but not 127.0.0.1, and is therefore not accessible for testing.  Can anyone help me to resolve this?  Thanks!

Comment: Our free VS extension called 'Conveyor' solves this without config changes: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score 6):

The issue is caused by IIS Express binding by hostname, and the host name is set by Visual Studio as "localhost".  Therefore "127.0.0.1" gives a "Error 400. bad reqest (invalid hostname)".

Solving this requires a few steps.

1. Modify the applicationhost.config

This is the configuration file for IIS Express, and should be located in the root of your ASP.NET project. If this file can not easily be found, right click on the IIS express in the task bar, click on "Show All Applications", and the registered sites should be in a list.  Click on the site you are trying to access.  Two File paths should be listed at the bottom, "Path" and "Config".  The config is the location to your applicationhost.config file.

The binding information would have the following format:

```
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:17687:localhost" />
```

The colon separated values in the bindingInformation represent the IP address to listen to, the port, and the host name.  You can remove the hostname to avoid IIS Express expecting "localhost" in the request header field:

```
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:17687:" />
```

2. Exit out of IIS Express

IIS Express needs to be restarted in order for this config change to take place.  It can either be closed via right click on IIS in the task bar, and choose "Exit" or by choosing the specific site (most times there will only be 1, unless there are multiple web type projects - ASP.NET,WCT, etc.) and clicking "Stop" and then "Start".  But Exiting out of it totally would be better as additional configuration might have to be done, and the PC might need a reboot anyway.

3. Firewall

The port that the test site uses should be included in the firewall.  In the case above, the port address would be 17687.  Open the firewall settings and add a inbound rule to allow this TCP port.  At that point, there might need to be a reboot.  At the minimum, the project should be stopped and restarted to cause a restart of the IIS Express.

Comment: There might be additional security settings that would keep the computer from accepting external connections.  I've found some Virus protection programs might block connections it deems dangerous.

Comment: You are a life saver. just a note, if you use VS with builtin IIS, you will have to run it with admin privileges so it could open the port.   the configuration file in my case was at the  Solution\.vs\config directory. the .vs directory is hidden so make sure you have these set as visible

Answer (score 0):

You can change host file in Android Emulator (for rooted devices also). Here is how you do this.

1. Open console or terminal (windows/linux)
2. Check if emulator is connected: `adb devices`
3. Call this:

   Linux: `adb pull /system/etc/hosts /home/"yourusername"/`

   Windows: `adb pull /system/etc/hosts C:/hosts`
4. Open `hosts` file and add line below

   `yourdomainputhere      benjin.local`
5. Save this file and push to the emulator
6. `adb remount`
7. `adb push /home/yourusername/hosts /system/etc`

Now you can access this url, like benjin.local

Comment: Right now, the hosts file reads only `127.0.0.1      localhost`.  What do I add?  By my understanding, the server is only exposed to my desktop's localhost, not to the emulator.  I suspect the solution lies in ASP.net/IIS configuration, not Android.

Comment: Add your address that need to be accessed http://10.0.2.2:9000/api/Maps/1   with some name after that

Comment: I may be having a brainfart, but I'm not sure how that will help.  `hosts` files work by directing (e.g.) "localhost" to 127.0.0.1.  I assume that I can't use the "localhost" keyword in the emulator, as that would refer to the emulator, rather than the computer running the emulator, right?

Comment: Use some other word for description. Like I write before "benjin.local". So you can access with this to your url

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding.  The emulator is accessing 127.0.0.1:9000 just fine.  The problem is that my server is exposed on localhost but not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: For that you define your address here, in hosts file

Comment: You're error is because it is looking for the hostname in the request headers to be "localhost".  that is the in the applicationhost.config and should be located in the root of your ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator uses 10.0.2.2 in the place of 127.0.0.1. Because 127.0.0.1 on your development machine corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface.

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a bog standard ASP.NET service right now, but on Web API, you can simply right-click the project, choose Properties and go to the Web tab of the property page. There I am able to change the *Project Url* field to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Having done that, the emulator should connect just fine, while your browser can connect to either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.